# How to compare size of the date with custom floating filter's value?

Tags: material-ui, datepicker, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

now I'm using **ag-grid** and implement custom floating-filter with **Material UI**.

I'm going to compare the sizes of the dates on the list.

For example, If you select 06/19/23 in MM/DD/YY format in one column of Custom Floating Filter, the list should filter data containing dates greater than 06/19/23.

1. Picking 06/19/23.
2. Data with dates **greater than** 06/19/23 must be produced.

Below is my code. Please help me.

- Column setting

```
    {
      headerName: 'TEST',
      field: 'test',
      filter: 'agDateColumnFilter',
      floatingFilterComponent: CustomDateFilterTyping,
      floatingFilter: true,
      cellRenderer: MuiDateInput,
      cellRendererParams: params => ({
        defaultValue:
          params.data.test && dayjs(params.data.test).isValid()
            ? dayjs(params.data.test)
            : null,
      }),
    },
```

- CustomDateFilterTyping

```
const HelperText = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider sx={{ width: '120px' }} dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker
        ref={ref}
        format="MM/DD/YY"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={e => props?.onChange(e, props?.branch, props?.valueSetter)}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
});

const CustomDateFilterTyping = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  // expose AG Grid Filter Lifecycle callbacks
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      onParentModelChanged(parentModel) {
        // When the filter is empty we will receive a null value here
        if (!parentModel) {
          inputRef.current.value = '';
          setDate(null);
        } else {
          inputRef.current.value = `${parentModel.filter}`;
          setDate(parentModel.filter);
        }
      },
    };
  });

  const onInputBoxChanged = input => {
    if (!input || !dayjs(input).isValid()) {
      // clear the filter
      props.parentFilterInstance(instance => {
        instance.onFloatingFilterChanged(null, null);
      });
      return;
    }

    setDate(dayjs(input));
    props.parentFilterInstance(instance => {
      instance.onFloatingFilterChanged('greaterThan', new Date(input));
    });
  };

  return (
    <CustomDateFilterTypingStyle>
      <HelperText
        ref={inputRef}
        props={props}
        branch="greaterThan"
        valueSetter={setDate}
        value={date}
        onChange={onInputBoxChanged}
      />
    </CustomDateFilterTypingStyle>
  );
});

export default CustomDateFilterTyping;
```

1. When selecting a date and then selecting it again, I found a problem that parentModel in the useImperativeHandle changes to null. Something is wrong, and I don't think the parent model should be null.
2. The types of date objects used between components are different. The MUI component uses dayjs to insert date objects, whereas ag-grid uses new Date() to convert them.